# Yii2 VerbFilter returns 500 status code instead of 405

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I want to allow only GET requests to my controller and I attached VerbFilter. The documentation says it must return 405 http status code when request's method isn't allowed, but I got 500 status code instead.

```
class MyController extends Controller {

   ...

   public function behaviors(){
     return [
       'verb' => [
         'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
         'actions' => [ '*' => ['get'] ]
     ];
   }

   public function actions(){
      return [ 'error' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction'
      ]];
   }

   ...

   }
```

Error message

```
An Error occurred while handling another error: 
exception 'yii\web\MethodNotAllowedHttpException' with message 
'Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: GET.' 
in /yii_project/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/VerbFilter.php:105

Previous exception:
exception 'yii\web\MethodNotAllowedHttpException' with message 
'Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: GET.' 
in /yii_project/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/VerbFilter.php:105
```

As you can see, previos error is duplicate of current error. I have no ideas about a reason of it.

Comment: 500 is server error, so I would guess you have an error. Does requests with GET work successfully?

Comment: @Jørgen Yes, GET work successfully. Error message tells about error while handling another error. So, VerbFilter giving two errors. Like I attached VerbFilter twice. But I don't. Wtf...:(

Comment: provide log for 500 error

Comment: @СеменихинМаксим It doesn't output anything in error.log

Comment: ok then provide full php controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first error: "`Previous Error`" - is 405 with redirect on error handler.
second error: your error action wants also 'GET' request but looks like got same type of request.=> infinite loop

specify action  for your verb filter and you will receive 405 error

```
public function behaviors(){
     return [
       'verb' => [
         'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
         'actions' => [ 'action-name' => ['get'] ]
     ];
   }
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I allowed all methods for error action, and GET for other actions and it works. Thank you!